# ruby test-unit test runner isnt running

Tags: ruby, testunit, test-runner

I am attempting to make a custom test runner using test/unit in ruby
 and have followed a tutorial outlined here

http://endofline.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/a-custom-testrunner-to-scratch-an-itch/

however when i try to run on it using the

```
ruby -rfast_fail_runner example_test.rb --runner fastfail
```

however i get the error

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- fast_fail_runner (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file in the current directory named `fast_fail_runner.rb`, right?  Ruby is not finding it.  You are following a very old tutorial and I suspect that old versions of Ruby had the current directory (.) on the load path or something like that.

Try replacing `-rfast_fail_runner` with `-r./fast_fail_runner`.